# What would a Green Party's position be when their country is under military invasion?

Tags: armed-conflict, military, foreign-policy, green-party

This question is referring to political parties that advocate green politics in general, rather than any specific party in a particular country.

While I understand that pacifist and anti-war policies are close to their heart, I am curious what would their position be when they are under imminent invasion?

For illustration, are there any historical examples of green parties having to juggle this dilemma?

Comment: Well, green parties are probably not different from other pacifist movements in that regard - depending on the scale of the conflict, and the nature and intentions of the invader, there may be several options, e.g. - 1. flee/retreat 2. stay and resist passively 3. stay and embrace/support the invader, hoping to change things from the inside. But the focus would certainly be on avoiding escalation of a conflict to that level in the first place.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "Green Party" here?  Is it a party that support pro-environmental policies, or is it one that uses the pro-environment stance as a cover for other policies?  (IMHO often to the detriment of getting general support for the environmental policies :-()

Comment: Could parties which were opposed to nuclear power be included in the Green party group ?  I ask because of the swedish Center party.  Which definitely were pro-draft for example.

Comment: The swedish Green party Miljöpartiet is pro an alliance free Sweden but they are not opposed to having an military with an deterent ability.

Comment: I think the "what would happen" aspect of this question is unreasonably speculative.  Predictions of future events are off topic.  The "historical examples" is rather short

Comment: This i8s too broad and too speculative to be a useful question here in my view. It isn't about any one party, or even about currently existing parties. It is about how parties of a certain general nature would react to a future event that has not happened, and in most cases has no clear precedent.

Comment: One more historical event that might be relevant, but I haven't  been able to find contemporary statements from the Green Party yet (only statements mentioning it in retrospect): In during the [Yugoslav Ten-Day War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugoslav_Wars#Ten-Day_War_(1991)) in 1991 there were worries that the Yugoslav People's Army might enter Austrias territory for tactical reasons, Austria (being neutral in the conflict) deployed some troops to the border. The Green Party held 10 out of 183 seats in parliament (Nationalrat) during that time.

Comment: No actual combat happened, the Yugoslav People's Army did not cross the border. There were a few "accidental" airspace violations by serbian fighter jets. One jet even got as far as the city of Graz - the pilot was a Croatian deserter of the Yugoslav army, and landed the jet in the Austrian city of Klagenfurt. [the jet was later handed over to croatia](https://www.krone.at/1917633) (sorry for quoting "Kronen Zeitung", not the best newspaper in general).

Answer (score 11):

Historically, the German Green party has been closely tied to disarmament and anti-war groups. Yet in 1999, as a member of a coalition government, they [supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joschka_Fischer#Western_Balkans_policy) a German participation in the Kosovo peace enforcement action (i.e. war).

The internal debate was highly controversial. Some argued that they had vowed "never again war" **and** "never again genocide", and that war was necessary to prevent genocide. It was the lesser evil. Others disagreed, to the extent they attacked the Foreign Secretary Fischer with a paint bag that ruptured his eardrum.

Answer (score 2):

Green parties started to form in the 1980s, and there have been few invasions of democratic nations since then. Without wanting to do into who counts as democratic, if we accept Green parties as being relevant only in western European politics so far, then the 1982 invasion of the Falklands becomes the only incident to consider.

[List of Invasions on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_invasions)

This predates the founding of the Green Party in the UK, but its precessor the [Ecology Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecology_Party) existed. I was not able to find their position on the Falklands war, but anyway I would consider them rather fringe compared to the extant Green parties.

I am aware of mainstream Green Parties in Germany, Austria and Finland. Of these, I am positive that those in Germany and Austria consider an invasion of their countries as far too implausible to have a policy on it. Having a border to Russia, there may be more concern in Finland, but not being able to read Finnish, I can't follow the details here. The Finnish Green party is in favour of abolishing the draft.

If you want to see how a Green party has handled a clash between pacifism and other values, I agree with o.m. that the debate surrounding the German Green parties support for the German involvement in the Kosovo conflict is going to be your best bet. This was not merely remarkable because a Green party support military action in government, but because the Federal Republic of Germany had adhered to a "no armed German soldiers on foreign ground" policy until then. Germany's prior involvement in eg UK peacekeeping operations were restricted to unarmed roles.